# Go passing the test case while giving 500 as the response

Tags: rest, unit-testing, go

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", path, nil)
response := httptest.NewRecorder()
r.ServeHTTP(response, request)
var raw map[string]map[string]string
_ = json.Unmarshal(response.Body.Bytes(), &raw)
details := raw["response"]
```

I have a TestFunction in which I am using this code. It is code
to test the REST API for a GET request.

In my first test case I hit a defined handler while in the second test case I am hitting some random handler so as to make that case fail.

The code is getting passed but every time the second test case is giving 500 as the response.

Below is the code of my test case.

```
func TestGetProviders(t *testing.T) {
type args struct {
    path    string
    handler gin.HandlerFunc
}
tests := []struct {
    name string
    args args
    want bool
}{
    {
        "First",
        args{
            "/api/v1/providers",
            GetProviders,
        },
        true,
    },
    {
        "Second",
        args{
            "/demo",
            TheFunc,
        },
        false,
    },
}
for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
        value := copyCodeGet(tt.args.path, tt.args.handler)
        if len(value["response"]) > 0 {
            statusCode, _ := strconv.Atoi(value["response"]["code"])
            if val := statusCode == config.SuccessCode && value["response"]["message"] == config.SuccessMsg; val != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("Error is:%v && Status code should be %v, was %d.", value, http.StatusOK, statusCode)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code that is not working as you expect? the `TheFunc`?

Comment: ... also don't ignore the error from `json.Unmarshal`, it just might point you to your bug.

Comment: func TheFunc(c *gin.Context) {
 GetErrResponseList(c, config.FailureMsg, nil, nil)
}                                                                                                                             
  it is just a simple function which will give 400 as the response code.

Comment: Actually your second test case makes little to no sense... assuming `TestGetProviders` is inteded to test `GetProviders` then there is no point for your second test case as it doesnt test that handler at all, it executes a different handler with a different endpoint, you gain no knowledge about GetProviders from that test case.

Comment: but it should not be giving 500 as the error

Comment: what is giving you 500, and what should that thing give you instead?

Comment: the second test case is giving 500 response code on get but it should be giving 400 as the response code as i have specified it in the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180799/discussion-between-harshit-vadhera-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally After Some Discussion with

> mkopriva

I Was Able To Solve The Problem.

I have been Using Defer c.Request.Body.Close() in GetErrResponseList inside the

```
func TheFunc(c *gin.Context) { 

GetErrResponseList(c, config.FailureMsg, nil, nil) 

}
```

like this

```
func GetErrResponseList(c *gin.Context, msg string, data, count interface{}) { 
defer c.Request.Body.Close() 
response := ResponseControllerList{400, 0, msg, data, count} 
c.JSON(200, gin.H{ 
config.Response: response, 
}) 
}
```

Which Was Causing The Problem as a request body does not need to be closed in the handler. and so it was closing the body just before it could be used and hence removing it solved the problem.